# SQL query produces date field as expected, when data is written to Excel datetime is present

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, date, export-to-csv

Is there a way to force Excel to take a date as is and buzz off with applying any conversion logic?

The query below produces the inactive date in the expected format when querying data in TOAD - just a date, no time.  Yet when the data is written automatically into a CSV file to drive an interface, a datetime shows up for some reason and its driving me crazy.  Wondering if this is related to registry file settings or something.

**Original Query**:

select DISTINCT b.id SUPPLIER, NULL SUPPLIER_PARENT, NULL PARENT_ORG, SUBSTR(NVL(b.LEGAL_NAME,b.NAME_1),1,LEAST(80,LENGTH(NVL(b.LEGAL_NAME,b.NAME_1)))) DESCRIPTION, b.NAME_1 ALTERNATENAME, b.BN_REGISTRATION_NUMBER ACCOUNTNUMBER, b.BA_TYPE_CODE UserDefinedField02, (SELECT address_line_1 from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) UserDefinedField10, (SELECT address_line_2 from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) UserDefinedField11, (SELECT city from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) UserDefinedField12, (SELECT PROVINCE_CODE from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) UserDefinedField13, (SELECT postal_code from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) UserDefinedField14, (SELECT COUNTRY_CODE from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) UserDefinedField15, (SELECT phone from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) Telephone, (SELECT DECODE(INSTR(email,'@'), 0, NULL, DECODE(INSTR(email,'.'), 0, NULL, DECODE(INSTR(email,' '), 0, email, NULL))) from ba_addresses where b.id = ba_id and ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = 'MAIN' AND ROWNUM=1) EmailAddress, NVL(f.PAYMENT_CODE,'STD') PaymentMethod, DECODE(f.AP_CREDIT_DAYS, NULL, 'N' || TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM TO_CHAR(NVL((SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SYS_DFLT_VALUE)) FROM SYSTEM_DEFAULTS WHERE SYS_DFLT_FIELD = 'AP_CREDIT_DAYS'),'0'))), 'N'||TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM TO_CHAR(f.AP_CREDIT_DAYS))) PaymentTerms, '*' ORGANIZATION, 'EN' LANGUAGE, '-' OUTOFSERVICE, **CAST(B.INACTIVE_DATE as date) INACTIVEDATE**, 'CAD' Currency from business_associates b, FA_BA_Properties f, audit_business_associates ab, audit_ba_addresses aba, audit_fa_ba_properties afa where b.ID = f.BA_ID(+) and b.id = ab.ID(+) and b.id = aba.ba_id(+) and b.ID = afa.BA_ID(+) and (ab.AUDIT_TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE-2 or aba.AUDIT_TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE-2 or afa.AUDIT_TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE-2) order by b.ID desc

I've tried variations of the query below as noted but the problem always arises when the data hits Excel.

- Trunc(B.INACTIVE_DATE) INACTIVEDATE
- to_char(Trunc(B.INACTIVE_DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD') INACTIVEDATE
- to_char(Trunc(B.INACTIVE_DATE), 'DD/MM/YYYY') INACTIVEDATE
- to_char(Trunc(B.INACTIVE_DATE), 'yyyy/mm/dd') INACTIVEDATE

I've been searching for a solution for this for weeks, I'm not a developer by any means, just a lowly analyst trying to solve a business issue.

Comment: Can you please edit the question in order to be able to read well.

Comment: So what does the date value look like in the CSV (open via something like Notepad++). If it's just a date, then your problem is with Excel column format.

Comment: The date shows up like this "06/07/2022 12:00:00 AM"  In Toad, there's no sign of 12:00:00 AM.  Thanks so much!

Comment: And is that BEFORE you opened the CSV in Excel? Export a sample CSV from Toad, then open it via Notepad++. Do not open in Excel.

Comment: Good question.  I opened with NotePad and NotePad++ after generating the file but without opening in Excel first.  Thanks so very for taking time to help out!

Comment: So are you saying that the CSV, before it's touched by Excel, is showing the Time in the output? Regardless, this just seems like an easy edit in Excel, changing the column format to short date. I don't know TOAD and if there are export features to take advantage of.

Comment: Thanks @isolated.  As the file is generated daily and used to automatically feed a web service for integration, we're aiming to require no manual modifications of the file.  I'll keep digging and will be sure to post the solution when I finally find it.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Excel will treat the date field as a string if you can have its values come in with a preceding single-quote.
Consider adding to your T/SQL query:

`SELECT '''' + b.INACTIVE_DATE AS myINACTIVEDATE`

Then, see how you like myINACTIVEDATE in Excel.

Comment: This is great @Mike G, thanks a ton!   I'll give this a try and follow up to confirm the results.  Have meetings all afternoon, so it might be tomorrow before I can confirm.  THANK YOU!!